# ¿Cómo convertir un String en Int en Java?

Tags: java, string

Por ejemplo, dada una cadena "1234", devolver el entero 1234.

Comment: Hola amigo podrias agregar el codigo que llevas

Answer (score 10):

> Para hacer la siguiente operación necesitaremos hacer uso de la clase
>   Integer y de su método "parseInt" de la siguiente manera:

```
String numCadena = "1";

int numEntero = Integer.parseInt(numCadena);
```

> ¿Qué problemas podemos tener? pues que la cadena no sólo contenga
>   números sino que venga con espacios.
>
> Si los espacios vienen al princio o al final, con un simple trim
>   bastará para eliminarlos, por ejemplo `("1")`

```
numCadena.trim();
```

> Si tenemos espacio entre los números deberíamos usar el método
>
> ```
> replaceAll (" 1 3 45 6")
> ```

```
numCadena.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

> Una vez realiazdos estos sencillos pasos podremos trabajar con los
>   números enteros.

**PASAR UN INT A STRING (DE ENTERO A CADENA)**

> Para pasar de un tipo básico a un objeto String tenemos varias
>   posibilidades, por un lado, si eres un artesano, puedes simplemente
>   concatenar a tu entero una cadena vacía:

```
   int numEntero = 4;

String numCadena= numEntero+"";
```

> La forma correcta de realizar esta operación sería invocando al método
>   valueOf de la clase String

```
int numEntero = 4;

String numCadena= String.valueOf(numEntero);
```

> Otra forma correcta de hacerlo sería utilizando el método toString del
>   objeto Integer de la siguiente manera:

```
String numCadena= Integer.toString(numEntero);
```

Comment: hay te deje como pasarlo de String a int y de int a string por si acaso

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarle al op resultados de ejemplo sobre las operaciones que acabas de hacer?

Comment: si quieres te agrego otro codigo abajito

Answer (score 2):

Con el método [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-).

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");
```

Comment: es pasarlo a int

Comment: no a double men

Comment: Está de ambas formas. Dos pájaros de un tiro, pero si hay confusión lo quito.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int convertirStringANumero(String numero) throws NumberFormatException {
    return Integer.parseInt(numero);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es :

```
String numero= "1";
int parse_numero = Integer.parseInt(numero);
```

Sin embargo, esto puede traer complicaciones ya que no necesariamente lo que haya en tu string es un numero, asi que puedes capturar la `Exception`

```
public int convertStringToInt(String numero) {
    int parse_numero = 0;
    try {
        int parse_numero = Integer.parseInt(numero);
        System.out.println("El numero es : " + numero);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(numero + " no es un numero valido");
    }
    return parse_numero;
}
```